# Find out if a window has a child window

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-7

I get a window handle using this code:

```
var h: THandle;
...
h := FindWindow('MozillaWindowClass', NIL);
```

h is valid (> 0).

How do I find out if this window has ANY children windows?

I cannot use FindWindowEx(), as it requires a class name.

What I want to accomplish here is to find out if the MozillaWindowClass window belongs to Thunderbird or Firefox. It looks like Thunderbird has a MozillaWindowClass without children, but Firefox not, so it would be a quick way to find out. (I cannot go about the process name using CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(), because my code needs to run also on Windows 2000).

Comment: Don't believe the recent versions of MSDN for minimum requirements, they tend to lie (drop unsupported OS, but only sometimes/for some). [Link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830031). From D2007's winapi documentation: client: Requires Windows Vista, Windows XP, Windows 2000 Professional, Windows Me, Windows 98, or Windows 95. Server: Requires Windows Server "Longhorn", Windows Server 2003, or Windows 2000 Server.

Comment: What happens with MSDN docs is that when they get updated, any references to versions of the OS that are no longer supported by MS are removed from the API topic under review.  What you need is an MSDN DVD from 2002 and you can use that if you need to support win2k.

Comment: You don't need to use `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()` anyway. Given any `HWND`, you can use `GetWindowThreadProcessId()`, `OpenProcess()`, and `GetModuleFileNameEx()` to discover the .exe filename that the `HWND` belongs to.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: "minimum requirements ... tend to lie", I always hate that MSDN.  Makes it harder to write code that supports older OSes when you don't know what the OSes actually support, if you don't have old docs laying around. I wish MSDN would stop doing that, it makes no sense. Just because MS doesn't support those versions anymore doesn't mean that developers don't anymore, because we do!

Comment: @RemyLebeau: A recent source of worries in my life is that most of the pages I read at MSDN are now placed under 'legacy technologies'...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way to determine whether or not a window has any children is to call [`GetWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms633515.aspx) passing `GW_CHILD`.

```
function HasChildren(Window: HWND): Boolean;
begin
  Result := GetWindow(Window, GW_CHILD)<>0;
end;
```